# Java: moving items in array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm looking to move things around within an Array.

I want to be able to move the last item within the given Array to a spot while moving those in the current location to the right. I want it to move from the first spot to the second, etc. without replacing the item that is currently there.

ex)

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

Say I want to move to "3" - it would then become

```
a,b,c,e,d
```

I currently have the following:

```
public static void moveLastup(String[] stuff, int position) 
{
    String y = stuff[stuff.length-1];

    for (int x = stuff.length-1; x > position; x--) 
        list[x] = list[x-1];

    stuff[position] = y;
}
```

edit: sorry I don't think I was clear enough. What I want to be able to do is given this method, I should be able to move the last piece anywhere.

```
for (int pos = 0; pos < stuff.length; pos++)
{
    moveLastup(list,pos);
    showList(list);
}
```

Now when I execute this, it simply takes the last item in the next list in the for loop
ex)

```
e,a,b,c,d

e,d,a,b,c

e,d,c,b,a
```

i would like it to show

```
e,a,b,c,d

a,e,b,c,d

a,b,e,c,d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more efficient and concise solution, relying on the natively implemented `System.arraycopy`:

```
public static void moveLastup(String[] arr, int pos) {
    String last = arr[arr.length-1];

    // Copy sub-array starting at pos to pos+1
    System.arraycopy(arr, pos, arr, pos + 1, arr.length - pos - 1);

    arr[pos] = last;
}
```

And some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] test = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

    // Move "five" to index 2
    moveLastup(test, 2);

    // [one, two, five, three, four]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
}
```

---

Regarding your edit: You're working with and modifying the original array. If you want to "start over" in each `moveLastup` you need to work on a copy. This snippet prints what you want:

```
String[] list = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

for (int pos = 0; pos < list.length; pos++) {
    String[] tmpCopy = list.clone();
    moveLastup(tmpCopy, pos);
    showList(tmpCopy);
}
```

**Output:**

> `[`**`e`**`, a, b, c, d]`
>   `[a,`**`e`**`, b, c, d]`
>   `[a, b,`**`e`**`, c, d]`
>   `[a, b, c,`**`e`**`, d]`
>   `[a, b, c, d,`**`e`**`]`

Comment: Are you serious? Thats what I wrote 10 mins ago, and also you did x>=position and that is a waste.

Comment: is there any way to alter the original method rather than the second for statement to make it display that "starting over"?

Comment: Well, not really. You would need to "undo" the previous `lastMoveup` before doing the next.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is about **Arrays** - don't wanna start a discussion about performance "versus" issues and "why I'm using pure array" - but for those using **List** I think this might be useful.

*java.util.Collections.rotate* method. Yeah, the name is weird, by check it out a part of the javadoc:

> Note that this method can usefully be applied to sublists to
>   move one or more elements within a list while preserving the
>   order of the remaining elements.  For example, the following idiom
>   moves the element at index j forward to position
>   k (which must be greater than or equal to j):
>
> ```
>     Collections.rotate(list.subList(j, k+1), -1);
> ```
>
> To make this concrete, suppose list comprises
>   [a, b, c, d, e].  To move the element at index 1
>   (b) forward two positions, perform the following invocation:
>
> ```
>     Collections.rotate(l.subList(1, 4), -1);
> ```
>
> The resulting list is [a, c, d, b, e].
>
> To move more than one element forward, increase the absolute value
>   of the rotation distance.  To move elements backward, use a positive
>   shift distance.

```
public void moveElement(List list, int a, int b) {
    // forward or backward
    int direction = a > b ? 1 : -1;
    // always from minor to major to subList
    int minor = a < b ? a : b;
    int major = b > a ? b : a;
    Collections.rotate(list.subList(minor, major + 1), direction);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your code you do

```
for (int x = stuff.length-1; x > pos; x--)
```

where pos is not even defined, I suggest on changing it to position.
second of all, change the "list" to "stuff".

Modified, working code:

```
public static void moveLastup(String[] stuff, int position) 
    {
        String y = stuff[stuff.length-1];

        for (int x = stuff.length-1; x > position; x--)  
            stuff[x] = stuff[x-1];

        stuff[position] = y;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason you're not using a `List<String>` instead of `String[]`? It'll make these type of operations easier. With an `ArrayList<String>`, all you need is:

```
list.add(3, list.remove(list.size() - 1));
```

Or even shorter if you used a `LinkedList<String>`:

```
list.add(3, list.removeLast());
```

Here's a more complete example based on yours:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"));
list.add(3, list.removeLast());
System.out.println(list); // prints "[a, b, c, e, d]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another short and quick solution based on `System.arraycopy`:

```
System.arraycopy(array, insert, array, insert+1, array.length-insert-1);
```

The array content is "pushed to the right" from index "insert".

Here's some demonstration code:

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
int insert = 2;
int last = array[array.length-1];
System.arraycopy(array, insert, array, insert+1, array.length-insert-1);
array[insert] = last;
for (int value:array) System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do like this:

```
char arr1[]=new arr1[5]; // arr1 contains a,b,c,d,e in order
char arr2[]=new arr2[5];

for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {       // copy contents to arr2
   arr2[i]=arr1[i];
}

for(int i=0,j=4;i<arr1.length;i++) {
  arr2[i]=arr1[4];
  arr2[i+1]=arr1[4];
  arr2[i+2]=arr1[i+1];
  arr2[i+3]=arr1[i+2];
  arr2[i+4]=arr1[i+3];
}

for(int i=0;arr2.length;i++) {          // Final result
  System.out.println(arr[i]+" ");
}
```