# delete and move elements in a table : java

Tags: java, swing

```
private JEditorPane textArea[]= new JEditorPane[maxTabs];
```

I've got this table,I want to delete some elements and move the others, for example if I delete the second element, the third will be instead of the second and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on scenario you are interested (we remove for example element at position 1)

1) If elements should be shifted to left and last element should be set to 0 or null depending on type of array like

before [0,1,2,3,4]
after [0,2,3,4,0]

you can use

```
System.arraycopy(textArea, index+1, textArea, index, textArea.length-index-1);
array[array.length-1]=null;
```

2) when you want to replace old array with new one that wont contain selected element like

before [0,1,2,3,4]
after [0,2,3,4] //we removed element at position 1 (new array is smaller)

you can try something like this

```
List<JEditorPane> listCopy = new ArrayList<JEditorPane>(
        Arrays.asList(textArea));
listCopy.remove(index);
textArea = listCopy.toArray(new JEditorPane[listCopy.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.arraycopy() to move chunks of arrays around: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5536023/150001

If you can, though, consider using a Collection class like java.util.LinkedList, which is much better suited to removing and reordering elements.  If you still need an array when you're done with your deletions/moves (maybe the API you're working with requires it), you can use the toArray() method.