# How can i move in string array item to the end of the array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
ipaddresses = IpAddresses.GenerateIps();
```

The array contain 56 items. I want item in index 2 to remove it to the end of the array.
So the content in index 2 will be now in index 56. The array size will not change only the order of the items. Item 2 will be in place 56. So now i think index 3 will be index 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: moving items in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535925/java-moving-items-in-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `System.arraycopy`. This is similar to what happens when you remove an element from an `ArrayList`, only in your case you are moving the removed element to the end :

```
E element = elementData[index]; // get the element to be removed
int numMoved = elementData.length - index - 1;
// move all the elements that follow the moved element
if (numMoved > 0)
    System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index, numMoved);
// put the moved element at the end
elementData[elementData.length - 1] = element;
```

Here `elementData` is the array and we move the element at the `index` position to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String text = "Cool";    
text = text.replace(text.charAt(1), "") + text.charAt(1);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain _how_ it solves the problem without introducing others and _why_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.